# \prevdepth error with mdframed and listings

Tags: listings, mdframed

I get strange errors with the last versions of `mdframed` (v 1.4) and `listings` (v 1.4). Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
\begin{lstlisting}
blah
\end{lstlisting}
bloh
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

The error I get is

> You can't use `\prevdepth` in horizontal mode.

which I don't really understand... Any pointer as to what is going on would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems to be a bug. As a temporary workaround you can put the `lstlisting` within `\begin{minipage}{\linewidth} ... \end{minipage}`.

Comment: Another workaround is to add the line `\makeatletter\let\par\@@par\makeatother` just below `\end{lstlisting}` (it seems that this environment doesn't reset `\par` to its expected value).

Comment: @PeterGrill: In this case the contents of `listings` can't be splitted.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Yep, that's why it was intended as a _temporary_ workaround.  I should have made a note of that in the original comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @egreg wrote in the comment it seems that `listings` changed the internal definition of `\par` without reseting. However based on great comments of @DavidCarliste and @egreg in the chat I fixed the problem.

Please try the [new version on github](https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed).

With the new version I get 0 errors and the following result:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps my answer above was too lukewarm: HUGE thanks to you for being so responsive! :-)

Comment: @Olivier: No problem ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you comment the line no 752 in `mdframed`, the file is compiling:

Comment the below mentioned:

```
\par\unskip\nointerlineskip\hrule \@height\z@ \@width\hsize
```

Comment: This would break many other things.